# setting up cloudfront with php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to configure the the amazon cloud front,  I have successfully created clouldflayer url and access private s3 bucket from it via console. Now I am trying to do it by php-sdk for that I have tried following code

```
use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;
$cle = new CloudFrontClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials.ini' => [
        'key' => 'credentials\pk-myKey.pem',
        'secret' => 'secret',
    ],

]);


$result = $cle->getCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity([
    'Id' => '****', // REQUIRED
]);
print_r($result);
```

but I am getting error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\CloudFront\Exception\CloudFrontException' with message 'Error executing "GetCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity" on "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2015-04-17/origin-access-identity/cloudfront/SDF345G";
>
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-2'. -

and  I have tried all reason one by one but its not working

Comment: No experience with PHP, but key and secret tend to be actual access-key and secret, not a pointer to the key file. Also credentials.ini may not be correct (again, no experience with PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-2'.`

Unlike most of AWS, CloudFront is not a regional service, it's a global one, configured and managed through us-east-1, regardless of the region where any of the related services (S3, EC2, etc.) are deployed.

```
'region' => 'us-east-1',
```

Comment: amazon aws  documentation is really crappy, thanks it solved my problem